# How to generate an addition equation for a number using only required set of numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I want to generate an addition equation for a random number which is look likes

> 5+10+2 from a set of numbers i.e [1,2,5,10,50].

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var setOfNums = [1,2,5,10,50];
var additionEquation; //ex: for randomNumber = 28; additionEquation = 10+10+5+2+1;
```

And the maximum number of elements in equation is 5.Is it possible in java script?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u clarify the question?

Comment: Can be accepted more solutions for a random number ?

Comment: yeah @Nitheesh. For example  my required number is 8, I want to display it as 5+2+1. The generated equation  numbers 5,2,1 are only from the set [1,2,5,10,50]. Is it clear?

Comment: yes @Alexandru-IonutMihai. But the generated equation numbers are only from the set.

Comment: ex: for randomNumber = 28; additionEquation = 10+10+5+2+1... Well if you allow multiple uses of set items then you will have many solutions... one being `1 + 1 + ... + 1 + 1 = 28`.

Comment: yes @Redu. The numbers in equation are less as should as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have multiple solutions. A dynamical programming approach could efficiently solve this;

```js
function getCombos(a,t){
  var h = {},
    len = a.length,
      n = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    n = a[i];
    h[n] ? h[n].push([n]) : h[n] = [[n]];
    for(var j = a[0]; j <= t-n; j++){
      h[j] && (h[j+n] = h[j+n] ? h[j+n].concat(h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)))
                               : h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)));
    }
  }
  return h[t] || [];
}

var arr = [1,2,5,10,50],
 target = 28,
 result = [];
console.time("combos");
result = getCombos(arr,target);
console.timeEnd("combos");
console.log(`${result.length} solutions found`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Then you may choose the shortest one among the results set. However calculating according to a `maxlen` will of couse save us from calculating excess results just to be filtered out later. So the following code only works up until the `maxlen` is achieved.

```js
function getCombos(a,t,l){
  var h = {},
    len = a.length,
      n = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    n = a[i];
    h[n] ? h[n].push([n]) : h[n] = [[n]];
    for(var j = a[0]; j <= t-n; j++){
      h[j] && (h[j+n] = h[j+n] ? h[j+n].concat(h[j].reduce((r,s) => s.length < l ? (r.push(s.concat(n)),r) : r, []))
                               : h[j].reduce((r,s) => s.length < l ? (r.push(s.concat(n)),r) : r, []));
    }
  }
  return h[t] || [];
}

var arr = [1,2,5,10,50],
 target = 28,
 maxlen = 5,
 result = [];
console.time("combos");
result = getCombos(arr,target,maxlen);
console.timeEnd("combos");
console.log(result.length)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I believe performance wise this can not be beaten easily. It takes only .190ms to get to the result `[[1,2,5,10,10]]`.

Comment: `a`,`t`,`h`,`n`,`i`,`j` - that's the evilest thing I can imagine

Comment: for using DP ! thumbs Up :)

Comment: @Sebastian Kaczmarek `a` stands for input array, `t` for target value, `h` for the hash table, `n` for the current number in evaluation, `i` and `j` are obviously loop indices. :).

Comment: Thank you@Redu. But is it possible to generate the equation with max num of elements 5?

Comment: @SuryaTeja, have a look to my answer too.

Comment: @SuryaTeja You are welcome.. the second snippet works up to the given max limit and solves in just 0.190ms. Compare solutions with bigger sets and targets and measure their performance to see how efficient they are.

Comment: @Redu. You are just awesome bro. Thank you.

Comment: @Redu, nice solution. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be **solved** with a `recursive` **combinations** of all possible `sums` until we reach the **target**.

One solution contains `maximum` 5 as a length where `5` is the length of the `setOfNums` array.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
console.log(randomNumber);
var setOfNums = [1,2,5,10,50];
setOfNums=setOfNums.sort(function(a,b){
  return b-a;
});
subset_sum(setOfNums,randomNumber);
function subset_sum(numbers, target, partial){
       partial = partial || [];
       s = partial.reduce(function(contor,elem){
        return contor+elem;
       },0);
       if(s == target){
        partial=partial.sort(function(a,b){
          return a-b;
        });
        console.log("sum"+JSON.stringify(partial)+"="+ target);
       }
       if(s >= target)
         return;
       if(partial.length>numbers.length)
         return;

     numbers.forEach(function(number,index){
        n = numbers[index];
        subset_sum(numbers, target, partial.concat(n)); 
    });
}
```